# Private docker registry that attempts a pull-through on images not found locally

Tags: docker, registry

I have a docker registry image running on a local network with the command

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=unless-stopped --name registry -v /mnt/part_sdb/registry:/var/lib/registry registry:2
```

but enabling the caching of images stored in Docker Hub requires one to pull the image, and push it in the local registry

Is there a way to configure the docker registry to do automatic pull-through if the image requested is not available locally **while preserving the ability to push local images**?

from [this article](https://medium.com/@andrenit/docker-and-artifactory-as-a-registry-mirror-1365891b39c5):

> The catch is that you will probably run the public Registry as a
>   mirror *or* as a regular registry, so you will probably end up running
>   two containers — one as a mirror, another as your local Registry (not
>   a big deal). In artifactory you can set up as many registries as you
>   want (local or remote), each with its own URL. Or you can “mix” them
>   on a single URL with a virtual registry (if you think it is a good
>   idea).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The entire subject is discussed in [Registry as a pull through cache](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/#run-a-registry-as-a-pull-through-cache), from where the below quotes are taken.

Basically you need to configure the cache as a proxy for Docker Hub:

> **Configure the cache**
>
> To configure a Registry to run as a pull through cache, the addition
>   of a `proxy` section is required to the config file.
>
> In order to access private images on the Docker Hub, a username and
>   password can be supplied.
>
> ```
> proxy:
>   remoteurl: https://registry-1.docker.io
>   username: [username]
>   password: [password]
> ```

Of course, you also need to configure your docker daemon to use your local cache (but I presume that may be already done from the context of the question):

> **Configure the Docker daemon**
>
> Either pass the `--registry-mirror` option when starting `dockerd`
>   manually, or edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add the
>   `registry-mirrors` key and value, to make the change persistent.
>
> ```
> {
>   "registry-mirrors": ["https://<my-docker-mirror-host>"]
> }
> ```

Comment: ok this does not solve the problem, as apparently you have to choose between configuring the registry as a mirroring cache *or* as a local registry. When it is configured as a mirroring cache, pushing local images is disabled

Comment: Right - it wouldn't be a *mirroring* cache if it would contain images not found in what it's mirroring... But your question update addresses that, I think.